# Postgres and Hibernate: Will hibernate_sequence properly generate unique sequences in production?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jhipster

Greetings and salutations ladies and gentleman.

I am using JHipster to create a java web app. I have created my entities using JDL markup language.

It looks like there is a hibernate_sequence that is being used to generate unique IDs? Is this good enough for production usages?

This hibernate sequence is required to be used when inserting data. Here's an example of the hibernate inserting sequence:

```
INSERT INTO SomeTable VALUES (nextval('hibernate_sequence'), ...,)
```

Why do I need to do this? Will this generate unique IDs for production database?

Of course, I look at the tables but I don't want any gotchas if I have to join tables at some point in a stored procedure situation.

Answer (score 0):

First, it's a good idea for each table to have its own sequence. This is good because in a really big DB there actually can be contention on a sequence, plus you'll "burn" through your sequence numbers more, so all of your DB keys will need to be bigint if even 1 table has more than a few million rows (or you're likely to get too large for the integer datatype)

As far as uniqueness goes though, you can use a single sequence without any other gotchas. There's a small chance of sequence contention, but that's only if you're inserting a blue million rows at the same time among multiple tables.. and I'm talking a lot of rows.

The key thing I'm looking at is that it that it appears that all of your tables may be using one sequence, which is not really how it should be done. It's a lot easier to set your keys to the serial datatype and let the DB manage sequence creation on its own, if there's an easy way to remove that code from your inserts.

Comment: Just for reference, the ID for Postresql apps generated with JHipster uses `bigint` by default

Comment: Well it sounds like a space waster/ speed waster to me. Not that a few bytes makes that huge of a difference, but when sorting keys, creating indexes, and having lots of foreign keys, it adds up. Doulbly so if you're running 32 bit version of PG.

Comment: And just FIY, if you're using one method to create all the keys, you might as well use UUIDs so the index trees are more balanced. Sequences one drawback is that it creates less than optional indexes over time unless they're rebuilt periodically. This is just a side effect of the table always growing and the key typically being greater than the sequence previously entered.

Comment: Yes, it would be better to have sequences per table (which is all a `serial` does, it's just a wrapper around `int`/`bigint` that also creates a sequence for that table https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL).  We'll keep this in mind for the next major release when we can have breaking changes

Comment: @JonRuddell What project are you speaking of? Are you on the  Jhipster dev team?

Comment: I'm referring to JHipster and yes I'm one of the team members